# How to set cookies for different domain using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, cookies

I am writing code that integrates two systems and i want to login in backend so no one can see the password String.

So this is the flow of the application:

1. I send request from client application (angularJS) to backend application (Java8 Spring) to access method at following endpoint (/orders/redirect).
2. The controller method asks the other system for token which is used to login.
3. I login passing the email, password and the token i got from previous request (that method returns redirect to the page where i am supposed to be logged in).
4. Then i want to redirect the client application to the url which i get from previous login function, but to keep logged in i need to pass 2 Cookies that i receive from previous request's response. ("laravel-session", "XSRF-TOKEN")

However i am unable to set the domain for the mentioned cookies. Thus i cant proceed to the website logged in.

I tried setting cookies with their domain with following methods:

with JavaScript

```
document.cookie = "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjlZZzlcL...; domain=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
```

or:

```
$cookies.put('XSRF-TOKEN','eyJpdiI6IjlZZzlcL...',{
                         domain: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
                         });
```

with Java:

```
Cookie test = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", 'eyJpdiI6IjlZZzlcL...');
test.setDomain("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx");


httpServletResponse.addCookie(test);

response.sendRedirect("url that login method redirects to");
```

I want to be redirected to the page (that one that login endpoint from the second application redirects too) but in the Browser while calling login endpoint from the backend application.

Also my question is if it's possible at all?

Comment: No, it is not possible. For security, browsers enforce a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_data_storage_access).  A page can only set a cookie for its own domain or any parent domain, as long as the parent domain is not a public suffix.